# How do prevent the debugger from quitting early when running Django server?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This is my `launch.json`

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django runserver",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        // "stopOnEntry": true,
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": ["runserver", "--noreload", "--nothreading"],
        "django": true
    }
]
```

}

The command generated

```
(env) USER@MacBook-Pro proj-api %  cd /Users/USER/Programming/Work/proj/proj-api ; env /Users/USER/Programming/Work/proj/env/bin/python3.7 /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.80290/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/wheels/debugpy/launcher 53020 -- /Users/USER/Programming/Work/proj/proj-api/manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading
```

I noticed `debugpy` wasn't in my env so I tried pip'ing that, but that made no difference. It does start however, it will eventually just run its course.

I have tried looking for any logs for the debugger, but was unable to find any.

I have gone through the vscode debugger docs for django.

I have tried variations of commands in the configuration, but no setting is making any difference.

Going through the debugger itself when `stopOnEntry` is enabled that last file it goes to before stopping is the settings file.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint anywhere? And you don't need to install debugpy; it ships with the Python extension for VS Code.

Comment: @BrettCannon I have tried it with a breakpoint; I put some in the view and model. It still quits which makes sense in this context as it doesn't seem to be getting passed the settings portion of Django setup for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `manage.py`?

Comment: @BrettCannon I have put a breakpoint in manage.py which does work, however, after I pass it the server continues to exit. Unless I am misunderstanding something the debugger is just calling runserver so the program should just always be running unless it crashes or is killed. I am getting no info which if any of those are happening.

Comment: So it sounds like the debugger is functioning, it's just that your server is exiting when you don't expect it. Best I can recommend is trace through your server until it exits to see where it's exiting.